# widow or widowed?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns

In the following sentence, should we use *widow* or *widowed*? Why?

> My father died when I was nine, and so my mother was a [**widow** /  **widowed**] with four young children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With “a” present before it, you would use “widow”.

You would say this as either:

> My father died when I was nine, and so my mother was **a widow** with four young children.

> My father died when I was nine, and so my mother was **widowed** with four young children.

So, in this case, it’s the first of the two sentences.

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct word to use is **widow**.

> My father died when I was nine, and so my mother was a widow with four young children.

This is because with 'a' you should use the noun **widow** instead of the verb **widowed**. Alternatively, you could say

> My father died when I was nine, and so my mother was widowed with four young children.

**widowed** is the past participle of **widow**

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Sorry, my mistake